# Trying to replace a point and spaces inside a sentence using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying te replace points and spaces inside a sentence with a dash using regex. I have now for example this:

```
String test = "Hello. everyone and ha.ve a nice .day";
test = test.replaceAll(" ", "-");
```

And want to result to be like this:

```
Hello-everyone-and-ha-ve-a-nice-day
```

I would appreciate it if someone is able to help me with a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
String test = "Hello. everyone and ha.ve a nice .day";
test = test.replaceAll("[. ]+", "-");
```

Or

```
test = test.replaceAll("[.\\s]+", "-");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k6eMLp/1).

The `\s` pattern matches any whitespace, not just a regular space char.

The `[.\s]` is a [*character class*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches a dot or a whitespace char, and `+` is a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) that "repeats" the pattern one or more times.